# To get the exact amount of data between specific date range and insert in table in oracle plsql procedure using varray type collection

Tags: plsql, collections, sql-insert, procedure, varray

`I need to modify the existing procedure. I have a varray type of collection. The data that will be inputted via screen needs to be inserted in ALLOWANCE_HIST table.

The program refers on the following tables named ALLOWANCE AND FEE_DETAILS `

`ALLOWANCE - ALIAS (A)`

```
MONTHLY_ALLOWANCE  NUMBER
START_DATE DATE
END_DATE   DATE
PERSON_ID  NUMBER
```

`FEE_DETAILS - ALIAS (B)`

```
PERSON_ID  NUMBER
PERCENTAGE NUMBER
START_DATE DATE
END_DATE   DATE
```

`Via screen, a person_id will input a specific date/period for their allowance subsidy application and the fixed monthly allowance is 10,000/month. Now, there's another screen and it's holding the data from table FEE_DETAILS . And whenever there's B.percentage (e.g 50%) should be deducted to A.allowance only between B.start_date and B.end_date.

When the person_id applied for allowance subsidy from 01-OCT-2023 to 31-DEC-2023 and then there's B.percentage(e.g 50%) to be deducted from 01-NOV-2023 to 31-DEC-2023.
Currently, this what I'm getting/output (which is incorrect)

CURRENT (OUTPUT)

```
A.START_DATE A.END_DATE  A.MONTHLY_ALLOWANCE COMPUTED_ALLOWANCE
01-OCT-2023  31-OCT-2023       10000               5000  
01-NOV-2023  30-NOV-2023       10000               5000
01-DEC-2023  31-DEC-2023       10000               5000
```

there should be no percentage deduction for October 2023, only from November 2023 to December 2023.

I need to get this kind of output to be inserted in another table named: ALLOWANCE_HIST which also be displayed on screen.

EXPECTED (OUTPUT)

```
A.START_DATE A.END_DATE  A.MONTHLY_ALLOWANCE COMPUTED_ALLOWANCE
01-OCT-2023  31-OCT-2023       10000               10000  
01-NOV-2023  30-NOV-2023       10000               5000
01-DEC-2023  31-DEC-2023       10000               5000
```

`

`ALLOWANCE_HIST - ALIAS (C)`

```
START_DATE DATE
END_DATE DATE
MONTHLY_ALLOWANCE
COMPUTED_ALLOWANCE
```

Comment: So, what have you tried that doesn't work? You haven't put YOUR piece of code that is not working